# The 3rd dataset not showing in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

My 3rd dataset is not showing up in the canvas. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here. There are no js errors on console. 
Its the dataset with label `Label 2`, line 40-44.

Complete html code - https://pastebin.com/pznuRccL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values turn out to be the same for Label 1 and label 2. I should looked closer